# Using multiple CASE statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL statement

```
SELECT
`Number`,
`Rider Name`,
`Horse Name`,
`Division Name`,
`Level`,
`Division Type`,
`Show Type`,
`Dressage Test`,
TRIM(Score1)+0 AS Score1,
TRIM(Score2)+0 AS Score2,
TRIM(Score3)+0 AS Score3,
TRIM(Score4)+0 AS Score4,
TRIM(Score5)+0 AS Score5,
TRIM(Score6)+0 AS Score6,
TRIM(Score7)+0 AS Score7,
TRIM(Score8)+0 AS Score8,
TRIM(Score9)+0 AS Score9,
TRIM(Score10)+0 AS Score10,
TRIM(Score11)+0 AS Score11,
TRIM(Score12)+0 AS Score12,
TRIM(Score13)+0 AS Score13,
TRIM(Score14)+0 AS Score14,
TRIM(Score15)+0 AS Score15,
TRIM(Score16)+0 AS Score16,
TRIM(Score17)+0 AS Score17,
TRIM(Score18)+0 AS Score18,
TRIM(Score19)+0 AS Score19,
TRIM(Score20)+0 AS Score20,
TRIM(Score21)+0 AS Score21,
TRIM(Score22)+0 AS Score22,
TRIM(Score23)+0 AS Score23,
TRIM(Score24)+0 AS Score24,
Marks,
Penalties,
`Net Results`,
`Result Total`,
(CASE 
WHEN Scratched = '1' then ''
WHEN Withdrew = '1' then ''
WHEN Eliminated = '1' then ''
ELSE Total
END) AS Total,
(CASE 
WHEN Scratched = '1' then ''
WHEN Withdrew = '1' then ''
WHEN Eliminated = '1' then ''
ELSE Rank
END) OR (CASE `Division Name`
WHEN @curType
THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := `Division Name` END
) + 1 AS Rank,
`Time Out`,
`Time In`,
timediff(`Time In`, `Time Out`) AS `Time Elapsed`,
`Speed Fault`,
`Optimum Time`,
GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`Time Elapsed`,`Speed Fault`), 0) AS `Under Time`,
GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `Optimum Time`, `Time Elapsed`), 0) AS `Over Time`,
`XC Time`,
`XC Jump`,
`SJ Time`,
`SJ Jump`,
(CASE
WHEN Scratched = '1' THEN ''
WHEN Withdrew = '1' THEN ''
WHEN Eliminated = '1' THEN ''
ELSE `Final Total`
END) AS `Final Total`,
(CASE
WHEN Scratched = '1' THEN 'S'
WHEN Withdrew = '1' THEN 'W'
WHEN Eliminated = '1' THEN 'E'
ELSE `Final Rank`
END) OR (CASE `Division Name`
WHEN @curType
THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := `Division Name` END
) + 1 AS `Final Rank`,
Scratched,
Withdrew,
Eliminated
FROM Scoring,
(SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
```

however I am having issues with getting the 'Rank' and 'Final Rank' code to work properly.  Here is the output of the table with this code:

```
N   Rider   Horse   Penalties   Total   Rank  XCTime   XCJump   SJTime  SJJump  FTotal   FRank
121  Poly   Wally                         1   0.0                0.0                       1
222  Wally  Ape                 35.6      1   59.6                               95.2      1
12345 Larry Hacking             54.7      1   0.0                                54.7      1
```

So as you see in both the rank doesn't work properly, nor does the CASE when statements to replace the field values of both rank columns.

I have tried a few different combinations of the code (AND, AND IF, OR & OR IF) but none of them help.

Does anyone know how I can fix this, so:

1. it ranks properly (1,2,3...), and
2. when one of those fields is selected it removes the rank from the 'Rank' field, and replaces the letter in the 'Final Rank' field, while sorting based on totals in ascending order, since the lowest total wins?

Thank you for any help anyone can provide me.

Comment: When you want to iterate and to use UDV then correct ORDER BY must be defined.

Comment: ```(CASE ...) OR (CASE ...) + 1``` in output list? obviously illogical.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this then, can someone please help.